# Read from txt list file and set many objects in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, properties

I, I'm writing an application that has to read the content of txt.
this txt is such a property file with a list formatted in this way:

```
1|Chapter 1|30

2|Chapter AA|7

3|Story of the United States|13

........
```

keys are separated by "|".

I googled a lot hoping to find any "pragmatically solution" but nothing...
how can I read these informations and set many objects like:

```
for    NSInterger *nChapter = the first element

for    NSString *title = the second element

for    NSInteger *nOfPages = the last element ?
```

Comment: sorry...fixed! thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

NSString's `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` could be your best friend.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_

Comment: thanks a lot! this method is not a stranger...but, my problem is to set each component of the same "type" (like nChapter) in an array for each type or in array of objects...

Answer (score 0):

Only if you read [NSString's class reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/iPad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"file.txt"];
NSArray *rows = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (NSString *row in rows)
{
    NSArray *fields = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    NSInteger nChapter = [[fields objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    NSString *title = [fields objectAtIndex:1];

    // process them in here
}
```